# Child process hanging multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-2.7, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am having a problem where child processes are hanging in my python application, only 4/16 processes have finished all of these processes are adding to a multiprocessing queue. https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#pipes-and-queues According to python docs:

> Warning
>
> As mentioned above, if a child process has put items on a queue (and
>   it has not used JoinableQueue.cancel_join_thread), then that process
>   will not terminate until all buffered items have been flushed to the
>   pipe.
>
> This means that if you try joining that process you may get a deadlock
>   unless you are sure that all items which have been put on the queue
>   have been consumed. Similarly, if the child process is non-daemonic
>   then the parent process may hang on exit when it tries to join all its
>   non-daemonic children.
>
> Note that a queue created using a manager does not have this issue.
>   See Programming guidelines.

I believe this may be my problem, however I do a get() off the queue before I join.  I am not sure what other alternatives I can take.

```
def RunInThread(dictionary):
    startedProcesses = list()
    resultList = list()
    output = Queue()
    scriptList = ThreadChunk(dictionary, 16) # last number determines how many threads

    for item in scriptList:
        if __name__ == '__main__':
            proc = Process(target=CreateScript, args=(item, output))
            startedProcesses.append(proc)
            proc.start()

    while not output.empty():
        resultList.append(output.get())

    #we must wait for the processes to finish before continuing
    for process in startedProcesses:
        process.join()
        print "finished"

#defines chunk of data each thread will process
def ThreadChunk(seq, num):
  avg = len(seq) / float(num)
  out = []
  last = 0.0

  while last < len(seq):
    out.append(seq[int(last):int(last + avg)])
    last += avg

  return out

def CreateScript(scriptsToGenerate, queue):
    start = time.clock()
    for script in scriptsToGenerate:
    ...
        queue.put([script['timeInterval'], script['script']])

    print time.clock() - start
    print "I have finished"
```

Comment: Why is that `if __name__ == '__main__'` inside your function and not at the module level exactly? (such as `if __name__ == '__main__': my_dict = {..}; RunInThread(my_dict)`)

Comment: Should I not have it there?  I have only just started using python myself however it doesnt seem to be a problem as my processes still start

Comment: Even though it is harmless to have it there when you execute your script, you will start having unexpected behaviour as soon as you import it. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do.

Comment: Anyway, back to the question. It seems that `ThreadChunk` is of your writing. You might need to post that too. Same goes for `CreateScript`.

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your code is that `while not output.empty()` is **not reliable** (see [empty](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue.empty)). You might also run into the scenario where the interpreter hits `while not output.empty()` before the processes you created finished their initialization (thus having the Queue actually empty).

Since you know exactly how much items will be put in the queue (i.e. `len(dictionnary)`) you can read that number of items from the queue:

```
def RunInThread(dictionary):
    startedProcesses = list()
    output = Queue()
    scriptList = ThreadChunk(dictionary, 16) # last number determines how many threads

    for item in scriptList:
        proc = Process(target=CreateScript, args=(item, output))
        startedProcesses.append(proc)
        proc.start()

    resultList = [output.get() for _ in xrange(len(dictionary))]

    #we must wait for the processes to finish before continuing
    for process in startedProcesses:
        process.join()

    print "finished"
```

If at some point you're modifying your script and don't know anymore howmuch items will be produced, you can use [`Queue.get`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue.get) with a reasonnable timeout:

```
def RunInThread(dictionary):
    startedProcesses = list()
    resultList = list()
    output = Queue()
    scriptList = ThreadChunk(dictionary, 16) # last number determines how many threads

    for item in scriptList:
        proc = Process(target=CreateScript, args=(item, output))
        startedProcesses.append(proc)
        proc.start()

    try:
        while True:
            resultList.append(output.get(True, 2)) # block for a 2 seconds timeout, just in case
    except queue.Empty:
        pass # no more items produced

    #we must wait for the processes to finish before continuing
    for process in startedProcesses:
        process.join()

    print "finished"
```

You might need to adjust the timeout depending on the actual time of the computation in your `CreateScript`.

Comment: I have tried your solution with the list comprehension, could it be that there is deadlock as I am trying to create files with all these threads and some of these files may have already been created?

Comment: Your threads might possibly be hanging in your `CreateScript` process. But it’s hard to tell since you shrinked it to `...`.